# Java Advanced Imaging "PlanarImage" class not found

Tags: java, jai

Let me start by saying I've recently inherited a Java application written using **Eclipse**. I'm new to this language/IDE, but I have a lot of experience with `C#` and `Visual Studio`. So, my problem may be something very silly, but I have a foundation so I'm not a total programming newb.

I'm exporting this project as a *runnable JAR*, using a launch configuration provided by the original developer. I have tried this with both "**Extract required libraries into generated JAR**" and "**Package required libraries into generated JAR**". Either way, 
I get the following *error* when I launch the application:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/PlanarImage
```

I launch the application using this command, where `appName.properties` is a properties file that's required for running the app:

```
java -jar appName.jar appName.properties
```

This occurs multiple times from separate stack traces. I'm not seeing any other runtime errors or compile errors. My JRE system library is `jre1.5.0_05`. I installed `JAI` by downloading `jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe` from http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/ and installing it into the `jre5` directory. My project did not compile until I got this specific version of java, and installed the `JAI` jre into that version's folder, so I am fairly certain I have that part together correctly.

Finally, here is my classpath:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_05\lib\ext\jai_codec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_05\lib\ext\jai_core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\junit4.10\junit-4.10.jar;.
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing *wrong* here? Is there any other information that would be helpful in figuring out why I'm getting this *error*?

Comment: Try changing your jar extension to .zip and extracting it, look for PlanarImage.class inside it. If you can't find it then it wasn't exported during your build. If you do find it then there is another classpath gimmick going on.

Comment: I found PlanarImage.class, but it's coming from an interface that's actually declared from within the project. It looks like the original developer created his own PlanarImage interface.

Comment: Ok, does it share the same package? if so just change your own classes's package

Comment: @MahdeTo No, they don't share the same package.

Comment: Then you should find both classes inside, if not make sure your packaging produces all dependencies in your jar. Consider a solution like jar jar or big jar. Try that and let me know

Comment: @MahdeTo so i have to get external software in order to include packages? that doesn't sound right.

Comment: No you don't, you need to package them, this makes it easier thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jar is in your classpath. Are you running from an IDE or from command line?

Comment: I'm running this from the command line using the command I have listed above. I added my classpath to the original question.